# send push to all devices with the same app from phone

Tags: azure, push, win-universal-app, azure-notificationhub

I have an UWP app which should notify all users of the same app if data gets inserted to the database.

On azure I have created a mobile app. And an "Easy Table" where I can insert data. Now I want to send a over my NotificationHub everytime something gets inserted.

I can connect to a notification hub but I cant send pushes over it

Is this impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I do the sending for the push from the UWP app itself.

For all hopeless Windows Developers I will post my solution as clear as possible:

First register to your Azure Notification Hub like you learned in other Tutorials. You have to make a test send over azure and receive the push notification.

After this works you have implement a code like this:

```
public static async void SendAlertPush(string message) {
     var topicToRegister = new Topic("something-notificationhub", "Endpoint=sb://something-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=blablabla=");
        await topicToRegister.SendAsync("hallo");
    }
```

As you see it is important to take the **RootManageSharedAccessKey**. You will find this in your Namespace where your notification hub is placed.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is possible**. You will just need to configure a custom script that will detect an update, and on update trigger a push that will be distributed to all registered clients (through the **classic portal**).

Some examples are outlined [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#register-table-scripts) (you need to register for the Update trigger).

To clarify, in the new model with the updated Azure Portal, you can use something along the lines [described here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push/#update-server). Essentially, you are capturing `table.insert` and triggering a push notification based on that.

Comment: He is talking about "Mobile App" not "Mobile Service". Your example is referring to the old Azure portal and old "Mobile Service", which does not have support for "Easy Table".